# How to include all php classes in one file?

Tags: php

All the questions here refer to how import files into a directory, I'm looking for a smart way that allows me to import all the classes in a single class. Specifically, suppose that I have a structure like this:

```
\ Root 'Main folder

  Bootstrap.php 'This is the main class

     \System
          Core.php
          Language.php
          Helper.php
```

Now in `Bootstrap.php` for import the `Core, Language, Helper` classes I should do something like this:

```
include "System/Core.php";
include "System/Languages.php";
include "System/Helper.php;"

private $_core;
private $_languages;
private $_helper;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->_core      = new Core();
    $this->_languages = new Languages();
    $this->_helper    = new Helper();
}
```

Suppose that the files are more than 20, it would be a pain to import everything. So what would be a smart way to import all the classes and access their functions?

Comment: You can use loop for this

Comment: you can use autoload function

Comment: @AmitRajput uhm sounds good, but should I create an object for each class? I never use an autoload function

Comment: If you don't want to use an autoloader you could just concatenate all your class files and include just one file.  `find . -name '*.php' -not -name 'lib.php' -exec cat {} +> lib.php` (as part of your build).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not really sure why you would like to do that but it can easily be done:

```
foreach(glob('System/*.php') as $file) include_once "System/$file";
```

May be you should have a look at autoloading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

```
// Register autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
  $fullPath = 'System/' . $class_name . '.php';
  if(file_exists($fullPath)) include $fullPath;
});

// Simply create a new object, class will be included by autoloader
$helper = New Helper();
```

This is a really simple autoloader but I hope you get the idea of it.

Comment: This will do exactly what you need it to however a much nicer solution is available using namespaces and autoloaders. I would recommend reading up on PSR0 & PSR4 to see how autoloaders should work.

Comment: `autoloading` help me avoid to create object instance for each class?

Comment: autoloading just following pre-defined rules for locating and loading files. You still have to create an instance of each class that you want to use.

Comment: the `spl_autoload_register` should be placed in the construct?

Comment: Should be defined in a central place. I would usually create a file autloader.php and include this as usual. The rest of my classes then get aotoloaded.

Comment: `var_dump($fullPath);` this return: "System/Helper.php", but this error is returned: `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Helper' not found`

Comment: Best read the docs, using the autoloader above assumes each file has one class defined.  So Helper.php would have just the class 'Helper' defined (one-to-one correlation between class and file).

Comment: Maybe you should substitute relative path "System/" with full path like "/var/www/myproject/System".

Comment: I fix the error adding `__DIR__ ` in your function, thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that `__DIR__` works in your case but the correct path is strongly dependent on the server enviroment and project setup.